# Screen Overlay Terror

Tags: screen, permissions, overlay

My phone has recently started a glitch with the screen overly prompt coming up whenever I try to access some of my apps.
I can't do anything anymore - there's this floating app I have. I thought it was share it until I deleted it, but the problem persists. It takes me back right where I started over and over and over again.

Comment: Shut down your device, power it back on, but press both the Volume keys as soon as the screen turns on. You end up in Safe Mode. Can you remove the floating widget app from there (in Settings > Apps)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I already know the solution, so if you start an app and it shows the the **screen overlay** text then you will have to open settings and try switching off all the apps which consists **screen overlay**. And if you won't get me, then you can just dm me the ss of your display screen and I can help you further.